# How To Fix `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined` in Router Link?

Tags: vue.js

I was working on my homework which I've got a problem in using `Router-Link`. I'm currently using `VueSax` Tables for SPA I'm working on it, and In all tables, there's not any problem with `RouterLink` but in one page i used Expanded Table of `Vuesax` which make table expandable when i click on it and show some data. Now what I'm trying to do is that i have a Lecture Table which every Record got some lessons and when i click on a lecture in table, table will expand and show lessons in expanded part and show links to lessons, but I'm keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined` in my console and links not working.

Here's the Component :

```
<vs-table :data="course.lectures">
    <template slot="thead">
        <vs-th>
            id
        </vs-th>
        <vs-th>
            Lecture Name
        </vs-th>
        <vs-th>
            Published At
        </vs-th>
        <vs-th>
            Operations
        </vs-th>
    </template>
    <template slot-scope="{data}">
        <vs-tr :key="indextr.path" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" >
            <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                {{data[indextr].id}}
            </vs-td>

            <vs-td :data="data[indextr].name">
                {{data[indextr].name}}
            </vs-td>
            <vs-td :data="data[indextr].created_at">
                {{data[indextr].created_at | myDate}}
            </vs-td>
            <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                <vs-button @click.prevent="deleteLecture(data[indextr].slug)" style="float:right" radius color="danger" type="flat" icon="delete"></vs-button>
                <vs-button @click="createLessonPop=true" style="float:right" radius color="success" type="flat" icon="add"></vs-button>
            </vs-td>
            <template slot="expand">

                <div class="app_lessons"
                     v-for="lessonz in data[indextr].lessons"
                     :key="lessonz.id">
                    <div style="display: block;width: 100%">

                        <p> lesson : {{lessonz.name}}
                            <router-link
                                    :to='lessonz.pathzz'
                            >  </router-link>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div style="display: block;width: 100%">
                        <p> desc : {{lessonz.description}}</p>
                        <p> path : {{lessonz.pathzz}}</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </template>
        </vs-tr>
    </template>
</vs-table>
```

So as u can see I've put `lessonz.pathzz` 2 times, first one in router link to , and second time is in p tag to test if I'm getting link or not, which it's working, everything is working except router link.

I also searched about it and I've got some solutions which it was related to app.js, but this method of using router for me was working for all my Homeworks.

app.js :

```
import router from './Router/router.js'

const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router
});
```

router.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import AppCoursesInstructorLectureView from '../components/views/instructor/courses/lectures/view-lecture'
import AppCoursesInstructorLessonView from '../components/views/instructor/courses/view-lesson'

const routes = [
  // Instructor Section
  //     // Course Section
  { path: '/clientside/instructor/courses/:course/lectures/:slug', component: AppCoursesInstructorLectureView , name:'view-lecture-instructor'},

  { path: '/clientside/instructor/courses/:course/lectures/:slug/lessons/:lesson', component: AppCoursesInstructorLessonView , name:'view-lesson-instructor'},

]

const router = new VueRouter(
{
    routes,
    hashbang : false,
    mode : 'history'
}
)

export default router
```

I've tried, 1.Suggestions on app.js

2. Updated Vue Router
3. tried to put my router link in template part of expanded table.
4. check api to see if path is working which it was working, and as i said in top i printed in a p tag.

I'm also using Laravel as Back-end and i'm using resource for my api which data will be received like this:

data->courses->lectures

data->courses->lectures->lessons

Vuesax Table : https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/table.html#multiple-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `Vuesax` Tables. whatever, whenever i tried to use router-link in expanded, didn't worked. so i just used Vuetify and worked fine. 
I don't know why it didn't worked but whatever it is, u can't use reouter-link in expanded, because it's not even access-able in Vue Development Tools in Chrome.

Comment: I have the same problem (and I'm using Vuetify).

Comment: His is this similar to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925954/vitest-error-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-resolve