# Vitest error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')" (router.resolve)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I have a very basic test, however it throws the error below when I try to mount a component `const wrapper = mount(HomeHeader)`. I've pasted my vite config, test, component and packages.

This error happened without updating my vite config, but I went ahead and updated the config with `test: { globals: true, }` so I don't have to import `test` and `expect`.

Full error

```
stderr | src/components/home/__tests__/HomeHeader.test.js > HomeHeader renders properly
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol([vue-router]: router)" not found.
  at <RouterLink to="/" >
  at <HomeHeader ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol([vue-router]: route location)" not found.
  at <RouterLink to="/" >
  at <HomeHeader ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function
  at <RouterLink to="/" >
  at <HomeHeader ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
  at <VTUROOT>

FAIL  src/components/home/__tests__/HomeHeader.spec.js > HomeHeader > renders properly
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.fn node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs.js:2068:45
    2066|     const router = vue.inject(routerKey);
    2067|     const currentRoute = vue.inject(routeLocationKey);
    2068|     const route = vue.computed(() => router.resolve(vue.unref(props.to)));
       |                                             ^
```

Vitest UI

[image]

Vite Config

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
  },
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
})
```

My test

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HomeHeader from '../HomeHeader.vue'

describe('HomeHeader', () => {
  it('renders properly', () => {
    // This breaks
    const wrapper = mount(HomeHeader)
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('MOONHOLDINGS.XYZ')
  })
})
```

The component being tested

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import {
  MOON_XYZ,
  LOGIN,
  LOGIN_PATH,
  GET_STARTED,
  SIGN_UP_PATH,
} from '../../constants'
import PrimaryBtn from '@/components/partials/PrimaryBtn.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <header>
      <h1>
        <RouterLink to="/">
          {{ MOON_XYZ }}
        </RouterLink>
      </h1>
      <nav>
        <RouterLink :to="LOGIN_PATH">{{ LOGIN }}</RouterLink>
        <PrimaryBtn :copy="GET_STARTED" :url="SIGN_UP_PATH" />
      </nav>
    </header>
  </main>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
h1 {
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.4s;

    .router-link-exact-active {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .router-link-exact-active:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    &:first-of-type {
      border: 0;
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    place-items: center;
    padding-right: calc(var(--section-gap) / 2);
  }
}
</style>
```

Script command `"coverage": "vitest run --coverage",`

My dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
  "axios": "^0.27.2",
  "pinia": "^2.0.14",
  "vue": "^3.2.36",
  "vue-router": "^4.0.15"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.0",
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^1.3.10",
  "@vitest/ui": "^0.20.3",
  "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
  "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
  "c8": "^7.11.3",
  "eslint": "^8.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
  "happy-dom": "^6.0.4",
  "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
  "prettier": "^2.5.1",
  "ramda": "^0.28.0",
  "sass": "^1.53.0",
  "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
  "vite": "^2.9.9",
  "vitest": "^0.20.3",
  "vue-tsc": "^0.35.2"
}
```

Anyone else run into this before while using Vitest?

[image]

Comment: so many unanswered vitest qu's on here, I'm wondering if I should go back to jest..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue Router is automatically mocked and because of that, no methods can be called from it. That's the reason why you are getting errors on calling `resolve()`.

Correct test should look like this:

```js
import { vi } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HomeHeader from '../HomeHeader.vue'

// you need to mock router
vi.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  resolve: vi.fn(),
}));

describe('HomeHeader', () => {
  it('renders properly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(HomeHeader)
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('MOONHOLDINGS.XYZ')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I can award in a few hours, that fixed the current error. Now I'm getting `TypeError: useRouter is not a function` on a button inside of a child component, this keeps up may have to end up using Jest until Vitest improves.

Comment: You will most likely face the same issues using jest :) Since your test does not depend on child component and as it's always best to test just the component itself, you may replace `mount` with `shallowMount`. It will only mount the tested component and stub the child component(s).

Comment: Just found out that Vitest is not recommended for production use as of Feb 2022 lol, yeah gonna stick with Jest and Cypress. :)

Comment: OH and I found one of your other answers! And did use shallowMount, then got some cannot split error. So yeah, vitest ain't ready.

Comment: Ah, in that case, jest doesn't seem that bad any more.